# What does the SPID abbreviation stand for?

Tags: ps, proc

The `ps` command with the `-T` flag outputs the SPID column, which is also called TID(Thread ID). But what does SPID stand for?

The `ps` source code doesn't seem to know why this name is either:

```c
trace("-T adds strange SPID column (old sproc() threads?)\n");
```

https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/newlib/src/ps/parser.c#L320

Answer (score 2):

The reference to [`sproc`](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/IRIX/man2/man2/sproc.2.html), which creates a new “share group” process on IRIX, (similar to a thread on Linux) suggests that SPID could refer to something like “share group process id”.

As you say, in practice on Linux `ps` shows the thread id in the SPID column, *i.e.* the process id from the kernel’s perspective (the process id shown in `ps`’s PID column is the process group id from the kernel’s perspective). This is the same information as is shown in the LWP column with the `-L` option. It’s not clear whether this actually matches the IRIX behaviour; [the IRIX `ps` man page](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/IRIX/man1/ps.1.html) doesn’t mention an SPID column; it documents the `-T` option as

> List data for individual kernel threads.  Normally the
> information presented is a summation across all threads of
> the process.  This is of use when examining POSIX threaded
> processes.

Answer (score 0):

SPID in procps `ps` displays the TID or Thread ID.  As opposed to the PID and TGID columns that display a process or threads process ID.

A process has the same process and thread ids. Any thread for that process will also share the process ID, but the thread ID is different.

```
$ ps -L -o pid,tgid,tid,spid,cmd 232810
    PID    TGID     TID    SPID CMD
 232810  232810  232810  232810 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
 232810  232810  232811  232811 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
 232810  232810  232813  232813 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
 232810  232810  232814  232814 /usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server
```

There is the main process of 232810 and then three threads 232811, 232813 and 232814.

tid and spid are aliases, they both call the same function to print the same value. The difference being SPID comes from an SGI operating system and TID from AIX.